# How to add an adjacent row and a previous (current) row's value in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new column that uses a percentage of its own previous value to add on top of a value from an adjacent row.

For example, at 50%, I want to see this:

```
# original
x = 1:10
# 1
# 2 
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
# 10
```

I want to get

```
# 1
# 2.5
# 4.25
# 6.125
# 8.0625
# 10.03125
# 12.015625
# 14.0078125
# 16.00390625
# 18.00195313
```

I can figure out how to do this with a `for` loop, but I was wondering if there was any way to use `apply()` or anything else that leverages R's capabilities to be a little faster.

In Excel, this would be pretty simple:

```
B2=A2+0.5*B1.
```

Comment: It won't be faster than your approach, but the R disguise of iterative looping is `?Reduce`: `Reduce(function(prev, after) after + 0.5*prev, x, accumulate = TRUE)`.

Comment: Also, consider wrapping your loop in a "function" and passing it to `compiler::cmpfun` -- it should be significantly faster for a task like that.

Answer (score 2):

`Reduce` is another option, for a detailed walk-through of how it works, see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101777/function-for-appending-rows-to-data-frame-based-on-previous-variable-values-in-r/38102237#38102237)

```
Reduce(function(x,y) y + 0.5*x, x, acc=TRUE)
 #[1]  1.00000  2.50000  4.25000  6.12500  8.06250 10.03125 12.01562 14.00781 16.00391 18.00195
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is a `for` loop

```
for(i in 2:length(x)) x[i] <- 0.5*x[i-1] + x[i] 
x
#[1]  1.00000  2.50000  4.25000  6.12500  8.06250 
#[6] 10.03125 12.01562 14.00781 16.00391 18.00195
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach:

```
f <- function(n){
    if (n<=1){
        print(n)
        return(n)
    }
    print(0.5*f(n-1)+n)
}

# for example
f(10)

# [1] 1
# [1] 2.5
# [1] 4.25
# [1] 6.125
# [1] 8.0625
# [1] 10.03125
# [1] 12.01562
# [1] 14.00781
# [1] 16.00391
# [1] 18.00195
```

In case you want to save the output of the recursive `f` function:

```
f <- function(n){
    if (n<=1)
        return(list(val=list(n), num=n))
    back <- f(n-1)
    back$val <- c(back$val, (0.5*back$val[[n-1]]+n))
    back$num <- c(back$num, n)
    return(back)
}

# for example
res <- f(10)

unlist(res$val)

# [1]  1.00000  2.50000  4.25000  6.12500  8.06250 10.03125 12.01562 
# 14.00781 16.00391 18.00195
```